# Handling Hung Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Can someone guide me on how can we handle a Thread if it is hung somewhere in its task execution in Java?

Suppose we have 10 threads created by a parent thread and the first child thread is hung in its execution in this scenario I want the rest of the 9 thread to execute their part normally.
So total in how many different ways can we achieve this? - In Java

P.S- This was asked to me in an interview.

Comment: can you share some sample code, where you show the idea?

Answer (score 1):

Its better to analyse figure out why the thread is going on hung state and  fix it. there must be some reason for going to hung state. 
Otherwise, you could check whether thread is getting completed within X milisec or not, If not getting  completed, terminate it.

Comment: I understand that we have to fix the root cause here, but from the interviewer question perspective, he was keener on understanding how we can continue our remaining thread with there execution. So say suppose multiple threads are there but due to one thread the execution of other threads should not be affected. So how can we achieve that??

Comment: @SwapnilTyagi, If somebody asked me that question in an interview, I would _insist_ that it is not appropriate to waste time trying to make the program resilient against hung threads. There are only two reasonable options. (1) Find out why the thread hangs, and then fix the code so that it _can not happen,_ or (2) re-architect the system to run as multiple _processes_, so that if a process hangs, it can be safely killed, and some kind of meaningful recovery can be performed.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you should investigate and try to find the core reason because of which the thread is getting hung.

Implementation-wise I would go for a listener/observer pattern where all the child threads can notify the parent thread after its work is completed. For this, the parent will have reference to all its child threads. Once all the children have notified the parent, it can safely de-allocate all resources and terminate itself.

In the case where a child thread never responds to the parent, you can define a `max-time-out` above which you deem a thread as hung and then terminate it from the parent listener.

Hope this helps !!